Configure Oracle Dashboard to email me if someone logs in
I am tentatively aware that people have been configuring Linux systems for years such that emails and notifications are sent to you through PAM and telegram and stuff. I haven't actually managed to get any of that working, yet. In any case, I am trying to figure out if it can be done via the Oracle Dashboard with its pretty GUI, not via installing things on the terminal. I would not be surprised if that ends up being the solution anyway, though.
OS: Oracle Linux 8
Platform: Oracle Cloud Instance - free tier
Why this isn't on Stack Overflow: I'm not sure this counts as a programming question. Adjacent, maybe, but it's about the configuration of a Linux Cloud Instance via a Graphical tool, rather than the programming tools. If it does fit there, though, then there were some older answers there which I wasn't sure how to adapt.
